# Getting Uncaught TypeError in Firebase Auth get current user email

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the email of the currently signed in user in my Firebase app, but it keeps giving me an error.

This is my code for getting the current user email:

```
user_email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email
```

The error that I get is:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPMkn.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `firebase.auth().currentUser` is null at the time when your `firebase.auth().currentUser.email` runs. This is quite common, as Firebase refreshes the user's authentication state when the page loads, and this requires it to make an asynchronous call to the server.

For this reason, you should not assume there is a user signed in. You should either put a check around your current code:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
  user_email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email
}
```

Or (and often better) you should use a so-called auth state listener, to have your code automatically respond to changes in the user's authentication state. From the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), that'd be:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;

    user_email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

    // TODO: execute code that needs `user_email`

  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried adding the if statement and I got to know that the user isn't signed it.
I was using it in a function. In my case I cannot ask the user to sign in before running this function as it would seem weird. How can I move forward?
@Frank

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Did you use the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` that I showed in my answer?

Comment: Yes I used it and it showed that the user isn't signed in. I added a alert command in the else statement.
Is there a way to prevent the automatic refreshing of user's authentication state on page load and keep the user signed in until he signs out?

Comment: No, Firebase always verifies the credentials of the user upon page load. You might for example have disabled the user's account on the server, which it handles at that moment. But if `onAuthStateChanged` fires without a `user` it sounds like the user isn't signed in. Since Firebase doesn't automatically sign the user out, you might want to check the calls going on in the Network tab of your browser's developer console to see what's happening during page load - and update your question with that information (and the updated code).

Comment: I was using a separate js file for this page. I brainstormed a little and got a way. I imported the js file for the index page which had the variable for user email stored and used the variable in my current js file.

But I am unable to understand you since I am a newbie to web dev. Could you please explain it in layman's language. It would be very helpful to learn a new thing